# whats the difference of these two syntax in declaring an exports variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, node-modules, mern

```
var exports = module.exports;
```

and

```
var exports = (module.exports);
```

Where would each be used and where would they not work?  I ask this coming from a MERN stack application where I have `routes` `auths` and `authController` folder.  The `authController` folder starts with line 1 of code as `var exports = (module.exports);` and its exporting handlebar pages such as:

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
  res.render("login");
};
exports.homePage = function(req, res) {
  res.render("homePage");
};
```

Please advise - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference at all.

The parentheses are entirely superfluous.

Comment: so the parenthesis is not affecting any triggers or speed of execution of exporting the functions within that folder?